# Filing stack of images in div

Tags: html, css

I can't fill my images to the single div, stacked all over. It seems like they placed in one line

```css
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  11.11% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  44.44% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.fadein {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: contain;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 4px solid #2e7645;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  /** outline: 1px solid blue; **/
}

.fadein img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 9s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.fadein img:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.fadein img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.fadein img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
```

```html
<div class="fadein">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" style="width:100%">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-350-150-1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-350-150-2.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>
```

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/mmqcLoaw/1/) to my fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is change the `position` of your `img` from `relative` to `absolute`:

```
.fadein img
{
  ...
  z-index: -1;
  position:absolute; // <-- this is the important change
  left:0;
  right:0;
  ...

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to fill your container, add after `position:absolute` (as [Niles Tanner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6739517/niles-tanner) mentioned) `height` and `width` value as `100%`. (BTW you don't need `z-index` property)

```
.fadein img
{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height:100%;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  z-index: -1;
  position:absolute;
...
```

And if your are sure that your pictures have the same dimensions, change your `.fadein` div's dimension to maintain proportion.

```
.fadein
{
  position:absolute;
  height:150px;
  width:350px;
...
```